# SVG fill figure and its negative in different colours

Tags: svg, gradient, svg-filters

I'm having trouble creating a gardient in a svg image. I need to fill the figure as its progress increase (0~100% or 0~1) but also the negative of the figure path.
Let me show what I need with some images to be more clear.

This is what I can achieve:
[Already Done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTaiT.png)

And this is what I need:

[Hope to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zt3TB.png)

Is there a simple way to achieve this?
EDIT: Sorry, this is  my SVG code:

```
<svg id="Capa_1" enable-background="new 0 0 503.353 503.353" height="512" viewBox="0 0 503.353 503.353" width="512" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<defs>
  <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
            <stop stop-color="#aaa" offset="0" />
            <stop stop-color="#aaa" offset="1">
                <animate dur="2s" by="-0.5" attributeName="offset" fill="freeze" calcMode="spline" keyTimes="0;1" keySplines="0.4, 0, 0.2, 1" />
            </stop>
            <stop stop-color="green" offset="1">
                <animate dur="2s" by="-0.5" attributeName="offset" fill="freeze" calcMode="spline" keyTimes="0;1" keySplines="0.4, 0, 0.2, 1" />
            </stop>
            <stop stop-color="green" offset="1" />
        </linearGradient>
    </defs>
<path class="kiwi" d="m483.142 269.401-1.281-12.05-12.05-1.281c-1.145-.121-9.029-.899-21.262-.838-.005-.412-.001-.824-.009-1.236-1.83-95.103-83.035-161.783-86.491-164.575l-9.426-7.616-9.426 7.616c-.768.621-5.382 4.403-12.108 10.948-24.406-55.352-67.489-90.736-69.986-92.753l-9.426-7.616-9.426 7.616c-2.49 2.011-45.318 37.183-69.764 92.245-6.44-6.232-10.835-9.835-11.583-10.439l-9.426-7.616-9.426 7.616c-3.456 2.792-84.661 69.472-86.491 164.575-.008.414-.004.826-.009 1.24-12.662-.098-20.841.71-22.01.834l-12.05 1.281-1.281 12.05c-.47 4.418-10.74 108.988 55.213 177.53 36.076 37.492 87.354 56.422 152.663 56.422 7.668 0 15.537-.269 23.59-.791 8.057.523 15.917.791 23.59.791 65.303 0 116.589-18.932 152.663-56.422 65.952-68.543 55.682-173.113 55.212-177.531zm-130.519-148.024c19.981 19.489 64.799 70.155 65.927 133.393.013.733.002 1.465.004 2.198-23.708 2.614-52.747 8.816-80.739 22.639-10.149-29.958-26.595-55.141-41.675-73.83 14.488-39.789 42.01-70.284 56.483-84.4zm-100.946 345.907c-44.573-42.071-66.743-86.537-65.926-132.316 1.127-63.242 45.954-113.913 65.926-133.392 19.981 19.489 64.799 70.155 65.927 133.392.815 45.779-21.354 90.244-65.927 132.316zm-.001-427.713c14.614 14.254 42.507 45.186 56.882 85.514-12.001 14.807-24.912 33.756-34.854 55.966-6.991-6.838-11.814-10.794-12.601-11.43l-9.426-7.616-9.426 7.616c-.767.62-5.371 4.395-12.082 10.923-10.056-22.312-23.091-41.309-35.146-56.097 14.441-40.021 42.123-70.704 56.653-84.876zm-166.124 215.199c1.127-63.242 45.954-113.913 65.926-133.393 14.402 14.047 41.701 44.292 56.249 83.765-15.218 18.751-31.923 44.168-42.187 74.464-27.697-13.677-56.423-19.896-79.991-22.557 0-.76-.011-1.519.003-2.279zm11.625 171.501c-43.922-45.516-48.054-113.042-47.706-140.938 21.81-.277 67.78 2.211 108.551 24.244-1.303 7.968-2.101 16.179-2.264 24.619-.936 48.66 19.036 95.238 59.414 138.849-50.56-2.269-90.153-17.923-117.995-46.774zm308.999 0c-27.843 28.855-67.441 44.526-118.002 46.781 40.382-43.613 60.357-90.193 59.42-138.856-.162-8.44-.961-16.651-2.263-24.619 40.783-22.038 86.768-24.519 108.55-24.245.348 27.909-3.787 95.426-47.705 140.939z"/>
</svg>
```

And the CSS class:

```
.kiwi {
    fill: url(#gradient);
    position: absolute;
    height: auto; 
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Show us the markup of your SVG: without it we cannot tell you how to proceed. See how to create a [minimal, concrete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Sorry, I have just added it.

Answer (score 0):

Well the easy way based on what your path looks like is just to copy part of the shape that draws the outline, put it underneath your existing shape and animate it using a different gradient.

(A slightly better way would have been to draw the shape using a fat stroke rather than a fill and put a different gradient on the stroke and the fill using gradientUnits= userSpaceOnUse.)

```css
.kiwi {
    fill: url(#gradient1);
    position: absolute;
    height: auto; 
}

.anzac {
    fill: url(#gradient2);
    position: absolute;
    height: auto; 
}
```

```html
<svg id="Capa_1" enable-background="new 0 0 503.353 503.353" height="512" viewBox="0 0 503.353 503.353" width="512" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<defs>
  <linearGradient id="gradient1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
            <stop stop-color="#aaa" offset="0" />
            <stop stop-color="#aaa" offset="1">
                <animate dur="2s" by="-0.5" attributeName="offset" fill="freeze" calcMode="spline" keyTimes="0;1" keySplines="0.4, 0, 0.2, 1" />
            </stop>
            <stop stop-color="green" offset="1">
                <animate dur="2s" by="-0.5" attributeName="offset" fill="freeze" calcMode="spline" keyTimes="0;1" keySplines="0.4, 0, 0.2, 1" />
            </stop>
            <stop stop-color="green" offset="1" />
        </linearGradient>
  
    <linearGradient id="gradient2" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
            <stop stop-color="#aaa" offset="0" />
            <stop stop-color="#aaa" offset="1">
                <animate dur="2s" by="-0.5" attributeName="offset" fill="freeze" calcMode="spline" keyTimes="0;1" keySplines="0.4, 0, 0.2, 1" />
            </stop>
            <stop stop-color="blue" offset="1">
                <animate dur="2s" by="-0.5" attributeName="offset" fill="freeze" calcMode="spline" keyTimes="0;1" keySplines="0.4, 0, 0.2, 1" />
            </stop>
            <stop stop-color="blue" offset="1" />
        </linearGradient>
  
  
    </defs>
  
    <path class="anzac" d="m483.142 269.401-1.281-12.05-12.05-1.281c-1.145-.121-9.029-.899-21.262-.838-.005-.412-.001-.824-.009-1.236-1.83-95.103-83.035-161.783-86.491-164.575l-9.426-7.616-9.426 7.616c-.768.621-5.382 4.403-12.108 10.948-24.406-55.352-67.489-90.736-69.986-92.753l-9.426-7.616-9.426 7.616c-2.49 2.011-45.318 37.183-69.764 92.245-6.44-6.232-10.835-9.835-11.583-10.439l-9.426-7.616-9.426 7.616c-3.456 2.792-84.661 69.472-86.491 164.575-.008.414-.004.826-.009 1.24-12.662-.098-20.841.71-22.01.834l-12.05 1.281-1.281 12.05c-.47 4.418-10.74 108.988 55.213 177.53 36.076 37.492 87.354 56.422 152.663 56.422 7.668 0 15.537-.269 23.59-.791 8.057.523 15.917.791 23.59.791 65.303 0 116.589-18.932 152.663-56.422 65.952-68.543 55.682-173.113 55.212-177.531z"/>
  
  
<path class="kiwi" d="m483.142 269.401-1.281-12.05-12.05-1.281c-1.145-.121-9.029-.899-21.262-.838-.005-.412-.001-.824-.009-1.236-1.83-95.103-83.035-161.783-86.491-164.575l-9.426-7.616-9.426 7.616c-.768.621-5.382 4.403-12.108 10.948-24.406-55.352-67.489-90.736-69.986-92.753l-9.426-7.616-9.426 7.616c-2.49 2.011-45.318 37.183-69.764 92.245-6.44-6.232-10.835-9.835-11.583-10.439l-9.426-7.616-9.426 7.616c-3.456 2.792-84.661 69.472-86.491 164.575-.008.414-.004.826-.009 1.24-12.662-.098-20.841.71-22.01.834l-12.05 1.281-1.281 12.05c-.47 4.418-10.74 108.988 55.213 177.53 36.076 37.492 87.354 56.422 152.663 56.422 7.668 0 15.537-.269 23.59-.791 8.057.523 15.917.791 23.59.791 65.303 0 116.589-18.932 152.663-56.422 65.952-68.543 55.682-173.113 55.212-177.531zm-130.519-148.024c19.981 19.489 64.799 70.155 65.927 133.393.013.733.002 1.465.004 2.198-23.708 2.614-52.747 8.816-80.739 22.639-10.149-29.958-26.595-55.141-41.675-73.83 14.488-39.789 42.01-70.284 56.483-84.4zm-100.946 345.907c-44.573-42.071-66.743-86.537-65.926-132.316 1.127-63.242 45.954-113.913 65.926-133.392 19.981 19.489 64.799 70.155 65.927 133.392.815 45.779-21.354 90.244-65.927 132.316zm-.001-427.713c14.614 14.254 42.507 45.186 56.882 85.514-12.001 14.807-24.912 33.756-34.854 55.966-6.991-6.838-11.814-10.794-12.601-11.43l-9.426-7.616-9.426 7.616c-.767.62-5.371 4.395-12.082 10.923-10.056-22.312-23.091-41.309-35.146-56.097 14.441-40.021 42.123-70.704 56.653-84.876zm-166.124 215.199c1.127-63.242 45.954-113.913 65.926-133.393 14.402 14.047 41.701 44.292 56.249 83.765-15.218 18.751-31.923 44.168-42.187 74.464-27.697-13.677-56.423-19.896-79.991-22.557 0-.76-.011-1.519.003-2.279zm11.625 171.501c-43.922-45.516-48.054-113.042-47.706-140.938 21.81-.277 67.78 2.211 108.551 24.244-1.303 7.968-2.101 16.179-2.264 24.619-.936 48.66 19.036 95.238 59.414 138.849-50.56-2.269-90.153-17.923-117.995-46.774zm308.999 0c-27.843 28.855-67.441 44.526-118.002 46.781 40.382-43.613 60.357-90.193 59.42-138.856-.162-8.44-.961-16.651-2.263-24.619 40.783-22.038 86.768-24.519 108.55-24.245.348 27.909-3.787 95.426-47.705 140.939z"/>
  
  

</svg>
```